# Use wired Ethernet for network drives but Wifi for Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Is there any way to specify what my network connections do? We finally got a 20 mb/s connection at my office, but it's currently only on our WiFi. I need to be connected via Ethernet, though, to access our network drives. I'm using a laptop, that has both an Ethernet port and a WiFi connection. Essentially, I want to be able to use the WiFi for my internet stuff, but the Ethernet for the network drives. I'm running Windows 8 RTM, if that matters.

I doubt this is possible, but I figured it was worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is quite possible. Just add a route to the internal network via the fixed NIC and leave the default route via the wireless NIC.

It helps a lot if you know how routing works. For that I suggest reading [this post on SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work).

Comment: Wow thanks. That looks incredibly complicated, maybe I'll just wait for our wired connection to be upgraded as well. lol.

Answer (score -1):

Just found the best solution:

https://www.ghacks.net/2021/11/09/how-to-change-network-adapter-priorities-on-windows-11/

This fixed my problem perfectly

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155163)